# Having a controller on 404 urls using Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to have a custom controller triggered when user hits a not-existing url or when I programmatically force an App::abort(404).

How can I do it?

My 404 views need some data, and a simple blade View (or a ViewComposer) is not enough.

Thanks

PS catch-all urls is not functional, because they don't catch programmatically launched 404.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `render` function of `App\Exceptions\Handler` class and add something about `404` here:

```
if ($this->isHttpException($exception) && $this->getStatusCode() == 404) {
    // Do what you want...
    // You can even use the $request variable
}
```

Full example:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception) && $this->getStatusCode() == 404) {
        echo 'hello from 404 renderer';
        dd($request); // Or you can a view.
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: I need to use a controller because I need some methods from hierarchy chain

Comment: Not sure it's a safe design to use too much controller inheritance. Maybe you could move these helper methods away from your controller. But assuming, you know what you are doing, my method does not work, so IDK how to handle 404 in a controller (I'm *still* think it's not the right way)

Comment: Why do you think this is unsafe? I got some complex logic to build pages. 
Hierarchy chain is not so big, I have just 3 layers with some shared views logic. 404 will be a complex page too, and it requires some of the shared logic. I cannot move these methods into helpers or ViewComponents because they depend a lot on which page is requested.

Comment: Ok, you are right! So I guess your architecture is too complex for me (I try to avoid complex architecture, that's why I also try to avoid inheritance in my Controllers). I can't help you. BTW it's "safe", I agree, I was just talking about "safe design in my opinion".

Comment: Anyway +1 on your question in the hope you will get your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to return a `redirect()` to your custom `Controller` instead of a `response()` from the `Handler`'s `render()` method if the exception is `404`. You can retrieve the the page requested from the `$request` then right ?

Here is the sample:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception) && $this->getStatusCode() == 404) {
        return redirect(route('route.to.custom.controller'))->with('request', $request);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Hope that will help, cheers !

Comment: This approach force an unwanted 301